# MutableSequence to pass as a list in isinstance() check

Tags: python, python-2.7, collections, isinstance

I built a custom list-like class based on `collections.MutableSequence`:

```
class MyList(collections.MutableSequence):
    etc... behave mostly like a list...

value = MyList([1,2,3])
```

Before processing list data, a third-party library runs a check:

```
def check_correct_type(value):
    assert isinstance(value, list)
```

I do not wish to convert my custom list-like object to a built-in list before passing it to the third-party library.

Is there an elegant way to make an instance of `MyList` appear as though it was an instance of `list` in the `isinstance(MyList([1,2,3]), list)` check?

Comment: Sounds like a fork or at least issue report on that 3rd-party lib would be needed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way instances of your class can pass that test without inheriting from `list`. You *have* to subclass `list` to pass that test.

You can try inheriting from both `MutableSequence` and `list`; any method or attribute not implemented by your class or by `MutableSequence` will then be looked up on `list`, so you may get extra methods that you don't want this way and those may behave unexpectedly:

```
class MyList(collections.MutableSequence, list):
```

You could also monkeypatch the `check_correct_type()` function, provided it really is a stand-alone function like that:

```
def my_check_correct_type(value):
    assert isinstance(value, collections.MutableSequence)

third_party_library.check_correct_type = my_check_correct_type
```